# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency issue in ios6 for tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

I have the app working fine in iOS5 but when i switch to iOS6, it is crashing due to UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency.

The error looks like this:

```
UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UILayoutContainerView: 0xa148de0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa148ea0>> is associated with <UITabBarController: 0xa64af30>. Clear this association before associating this view with <lkViewController: 0xa33faa0>.'
```

I have looked at some of the solutions on stackoverflow and it tell me to delete the viewcontrollers. But when I delete the tabbarcontroller, the view does not appear correctly.

My xib file looks like this:

[image]

Need some guidance on this..Thanks...

EDIT:

the crash comes in this line in lkViewController:

```
self.view = m_tabBarController.view;
```

when m_tabBarController is a UITabBarController.

Comment: What is an `lkViewController` and where are you using it? You're either connecting something to its view outlet by mistake, or you're setting the wrong view to its view property.

Comment: lkViewController is a UIViewController...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing

```
self.view = m_tabBarController.view;
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:m_tabBarController.view];
```

Will solve the issue...